# Ajax MessageCommand is not using Bootstrap Barrio status-message theme template

Tags: ajax, 9, bootstrap-theme

I have a Controller in my custom Module which returns an Ajax Response:

```php
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new MessageCommand('In den Warenkorb gelegt', NULL, ['type' => 'warning']));
return $response;
```

I can see that the response is working fine in my browser, as the message gets rendered.

```php
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--highlighted--system-messages-block--<active-theme-name>-messages.html.twig
   * block--highlighted--<active-theme-name>-messages.html.twig
   * block--highlighted--system-messages-block.html.twig
   * block--highlighted.html.twig
   * block--<active-theme-name>-messages.html.twig
   x block--system-messages-block.html.twig
   * block--system.html.twig
   * block.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/block--system-messages-block.html.twig' -->
<div class="" data-drupal-messages=""><div class="messages__wrapper"><div class="messages messages--warning" role="alert" data-drupal-message-id="warning-537390376486222" data-drupal-message-type="warning" aria-label="Warnmeldung">In den Warenkorb gelegt</div></div></div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/block--system-messages-block.html.twig' -->
```

I am using the Bootstrap Barrio Theme and my usual, non-Ajax Status Messages are rendered with an additional `status_messages` twig template like this:

```php
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/block--system-messages-block.html.twig' -->
<div data-drupal-messages-fallback="" class="hidden"></div>

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'status_messages' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/misc/status-messages.html.twig' -->
<div data-drupal-messages="">
  <div aria-label="Statusmeldung" class="alert alert-dismissible fade show col-12 alert-success" role="status">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    Magazine<em class="placeholder"><a href="/magazines/65" hreflang="de">Magazin 5-2022</a></em> wurde aktualisiert.
  </div>
</div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/misc/status-messages.html.twig' -->
```

Why is the status-messages template inside the system-messages-block not used or rendered when I use my Ajax MessageCommand Response?

Comment: Is the message being rendered on the page that is using that theme? If the message is being rendered on the admin theme, it will not use a template from the default theme.

Comment: @Jaypan , yes, the message is rendered on the frontend theme, which is a child theme of the bootstrap barrio theme